# Option key in Cocoa Emacs not entering accented characters

Tags: cocoa, emacs, internationalization, non-ascii-characters, tty

Using an international keyboard with TTY emacs works fine for entering characters:

```
alt-e + a enters á
alt-i + a enters â
etc
```

The problem is that in Cocoa Emacs that same doesn't hold true. These keys get interpreted as emacs commands.

I tried to unbind these keys globally, even unbinded they don't enter the correct escape character needed for international accented characters.

How to I get back to the TTY behaviour in Cocoa Emacs?

Comment: I build my own Emacs for OSX `--with-ns` and these are my settings so my right option key works with OSX natively and my left option key serves as the meta in Emacs.  `(setq ns-alternate-modifier 'meta) (setq ns-right-alternate-modifier 'none) (setq ns-command-modifier 'super) (setq ns-right-command-modifier 'left) (setq ns-control-modifier 'control) (setq ns-right-control-modifier 'left) (setq ns-function-modifier 'none)`  I don't use the terminal version of Emacs on OSX, so I have not idea what TTY behavior in Cocoa Emacs is and I'm not sure how that might be different than `--with-ns`.

Comment: Thank you. This is it, I tried a lot of very strange approaches and nothing worked and now it was as simple as changing the keys. It works perfectly! If you put this in the form of an answer I'll accept it as the correct answer for the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to have the best of both worlds on OSX, so I set the left alt/option key to META and the right alt/option key to the default native OSX settings.  Here are my settings for the commonly used Emacs modifier keys:

```lisp
(setq ns-alternate-modifier 'meta)
(setq ns-right-alternate-modifier 'none)
(setq ns-command-modifier 'super)
(setq ns-right-command-modifier 'left)
(setq ns-control-modifier 'control)
(setq ns-right-control-modifier 'left)
(setq ns-function-modifier 'none)
```