# Emacs on mac: changing cmd key

Tags: macos, emacs

I am using GNU Emacs 22.1.1 on macOs Sierra.

Currently I have the option/alt key functioning as the meta key whereas the cmd key is working as the super key.

I would like to have the cmd key working as the meta key and the option/alt key functioning normally (so that I can type curly braces, for example).

I have already tried this

```
(set mac-option-modifier nil)
(set mac-command-modifier 'meta)
```

on my init file, but it's not working. The init file is being loaded.

What can I possibly do to fix this?

Comment: Are you using Emacs in the terminal or the GUI version of Emacs?  Please consider upgrading to Emacs 25 for OSX:  https://emacsformacosx.com/  Here is a link to a related thread that shows how to get system default behavior with the right option key and Emacs behavior with the left option key:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/34933409/2112489

Comment: I am using emacs in the terminal.

Comment: See "**Use the command key in Terminal on OSX?**":  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7761/use-the-command-key-in-terminal-on-osx